# Passing JSON Parameters to Change CSS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to dynamically change an elements CSS using a JSON like so...

```js
cssSettings = {
  fontSize: function(fontSize) {
    $(".content").css("font-size", fontSize + "px")
  },
  color: function(color) {
    $(".content").css("color", color)
  }
}

var settings = {
  fontSize: "24",
  color: "red"
}

cssSettings(settings)
```

```css
body {
  background: #9effe5;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor dolorum architecto laudantium porro odit! Eligendi consequatur, totam molestiae. Nam laborum quam, accusamus quis distinctio corporis voluptatum repellendus optio voluptatibus dolorum!</div>
```

Might be sleep deprivation, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it this way.

Can someone help explain exactly what I doing wrong?

Comment: why are you using `cssSettings` as a function while it's a plain object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this. (Note untested.)

Css settings needs to be a function not an object. The way i tackled it was to loop over the settings object and if there is a matching function in the mySettings object it will call the function with that objects params.

```
var settings = {
  fontSize: "24",
  color: "red"
}

var cssSettings = function(opts){
  var selector = opts.selector || ".content":
  var mySettings = {
    fontSize: function(fontSize) {
      $(selector).css("font-size", fontSize + "px")
    },
    color: function(color) {
      $(selector).css("color", color)
    }
  };

  for (var i in opts) {
    if (mySettings[i] && typeof mySettings[i] === 'function'){
      mySettings[i](opts[i]);
    }
  }

};


cssSettings(settings)
```

I actually like this idea seems clean

Comment: I didn't even think about using a for loop.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One issue is the fact that you have `cssSettings = {...}` in your code, but later attempt to invoke it as a function: `cssSettings(settings)`.

My honest opinion is that it seems you're adding an additional layer on top of jQuery's `css` function that isn't necessary, because if you take a look at their [.css() api](http://api.jquery.com/css/), by default it's able to handle a plain object directly.

So I would actually refactor it to:

```
var settings = {
  fontSize: "24",
  color: "red"
}

$(".content").css(settings);
```

This way you don't introduce additional overhead that isn't really needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use **CSS classes** like so:

```
.error {
    color: red;
}

.tiny {
    font-size: 0.65em;
}

.small {
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

... (etc) ...
```

Apply them with jQuery like so:

```
$(selector).addClass("error");
$(selector).addClass("tiny");
```

This separates the logic that updates the design from the design itself.

Placing the colors and font sizes in the JavaScript violates the *Separation of Concerns* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns#HTML.2C_CSS.2C_JavaScript

Comment: I already know this. This wasn't the focus of the problem. Although it is good practice.